# How to aggregate an "others" row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create an "others" row of a pandas dataframe counting the forum rows in the data and calculating the percentage of the occurrences.

Original dataframe

```
            forum  ...                date
12       panorama  ... 2020-01-13 10:55:00
13           test  ... 2020-01-13 16:58:00
10         kultur  ... 2020-01-14 11:18:00
9        panorama  ... 2020-01-18 13:26:00
7          inland  ... 2020-01-24 10:46:00
```

My code

```
df = df.groupby(df["forum"]).agg({'forum': 'count'})
df['perc'] = df['forum'] / df['forum'].sum()*100
result = df.nlargest(3, columns='perc')
result.loc['forum'] = ['Others', df.loc[~df.forum.isin(result.forum), 'perc'].sum()]
print(result)
```

but this results in

```
               forum  perc
forum                 
panorama      10  62.5
kultur         2  12.5
test           2  12.5
forum     Others  12.5
```

what do I need to change to achieve the following output?

```
forum           perc      
panorama        62.5
kultur          12.5
test            12.5
Others          12.5
```

Comment: Can you share your sample dataframe for input?

Comment: Can you share the original dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the percentage, you could use `value_counts` with `normalize=True`

```
forum_percents = df['forum'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

```
panorama    0.4
kultur      0.2
test        0.2
inland      0.2
Name: forum, dtype: float64
```

And then, find top-3:

```
top_3_forums = forum_percents.sort_values(ascending=False).head(3)
```

```
panorama    0.4
inland      0.2
test        0.2
Name: forum, dtype: float64
```

Finally, add the "Others" row:

```
forums = top_3_forums.append(pd.Series([1 - top_3_forums.sum()], index=['Others']))
```

```
panorama    0.4
inland      0.2
test        0.2
Others      0.2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it!